# Can one ensure the separability of 3-qubit density matrices by requiring a positive partial transpose plus a range criterion?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

From what I understand, the positive partial transpose (PPT) criterion is not a sufficient separability condition for 3-qubit states. I have found that the range criterion is also a necessary condition for separability in these cases, but does it form a sufficient condition alongside the PPT criterion?